# How to use re.findall in a string with different patterns?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this XML:

```
<O X="2424" C="22" Y="37" P="0" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="29" X="2375" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="100" X="2306" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="105" X="2606" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="50" X="2479" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="36" X="2738" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="38" X="2876" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="304" X="2370" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="304" X="2469" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="373" X="2422" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="449" X="2420" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="560" X="2444" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="580" X="2274" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="649" X="551" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="648" X="866" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="651" X="1276" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="518" X="120" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="476" X="418" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="518" X="140" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="533" X="120" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="533" X="140" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="411" X="603" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="650" X="1900" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="450" X="1615" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="416" X="2080" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="220" X="2533" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="62" X="1941" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="456" X="648" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="486" X="388" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="467" X="442" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="355" X="960" />
```

And i need get the numbers inside of all X and Y, i tried re.findall but the patterns change in the XML. Someone could help me?

Comment: Separately for X and Y are all together in one match?

Comment: yes, i need X and Y separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
s = '<O X="2424" C="22" Y="37" P="0" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="29" X="2375" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="100" X="2306" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="105" X="2606" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="50" X="2479" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="36" X="2738" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="38" X="2876" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="304" X="2370" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="304" X="2469" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="373" X="2422" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="449" X="2420" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="560" X="2444" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="580" X="2274" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="649" X="551" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="648" X="866" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="651" X="1276" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="518" X="120" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="476" X="418" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="518" X="140" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="533" X="120" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="533" X="140" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="411" X="603" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="650" X="1900" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="450" X="1615" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="416" X="2080" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="220" X="2533" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="62" X="1941" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="456" X="648" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="486" X="388" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="467" X="442" /><O P="0" C="22" Y="355" X="960" />'

import re

x = re.findall(r'X=\"(\d+)\"', s)

y = re.findall(r'Y=\"(\d+)\"', s)
```

Then if you want, you can convert the number-strings to ints:

```
x = map(int, x)
y = map(int, y)
```